# How to install MongoDB tools on Mac

Tags: mongodb, macos, mongodump, mongoexport, binaries

I want to use some of the tools on MongoDB tools (for example mongoexport, mongodump).  I downloaded MongoDB tools from their [download page](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools?tck=docs_databasetools) which gave me a zip file.  I unzipped it, but it was not clear how to install the tools.  So I just copied the Unix executables to usr/local/bin.  But then when I try to use them in terminal, Apple gives me the warning:

[image]

Is there some way to install the binary files so that Apple security doesn't prompt for this every time?

Comment: "_I unzipped it, but it was not clear how to install the tools._". You don't need to do any _install_. The programs `mongoexport`, `mongodump`, etc., are the tools. These are run from the operating system command-line.  Also, see [database tools](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/).

Comment: Ok, but my command-line doesn't recognise the commands unless I copy them into usr/local/bin.  And if I do that, Apple throws a security warning which says it cannot check them for malicious software.  I want to be able to use them from the command line without any security warnings.

Comment: May be you can add the path of the folder where the programs are to the system `path` variable (instead of the usr/local/bin).

Answer (score 0):

1.you can go to this page (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/installation/installation-macos/) and use brew install mongo-tools

2.if you aplication need executable file, you can make soft link.